# GWT cancel SelectionEvent

Tags: gwt, tree

Ok, my question is simple. Can I add something like `EventPreview` for `SelectionEvent` in `Tree` class?

I need it beacuse switching betweeen tree elements initializes other part of screen which might not be always possible (e.g. asks for cofirmation)...

```
structTree.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<TreeItem>() {
    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
        // Do something, or maybe cancel selection
    }
});
```

### EDIT

If I add `EventPreview` for `ClickEvent` that would probably do the trick but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EventPreview` is deprecated, use `NativePreviewHandler` and `NativePreviewEvent` instead.

The event preview idea is for user interaction DOM events - the events that describe the physical actions the user has when interacting with the browser. This is why it works to cancel the `ClickEvent`.

In contrast, `SelectionEvent` is a logical event - it originates from withing GWT code, and describes the intent the widget saw from the user's 'physical' event.

However, there is still a way to prevent `SelectionEvent`s from occurring, but it is inconsistently used in GWT - the `Tree` widget doesn't use it, so it won't help you this time.
Other widgets, like `TabLayoutPanel` and `StackLayoutPanel` fire a `BeforeSelectionEvent` before the actual `SelectionEvent` goes off, giving you the chance to to `cancel()` it before the selection actually occurs.

Comment: Understood - thanks for clear explanation! :) I managed to get around this problem by storing previously selected item in external variable and restoring it if necessary. Thanks!